# ExtJS-based time spinner control

Tags: javascript, extjs, deftjs

I'm looking for the time spinner control implementation (as it shown on the attached image) based on ExtJS classes. Is there any like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

while defining parameters use type as numberfield to make the field as spinner.

`{
  xtype: 'numberfield',
  name: 'numberfield1',
  fieldLabel: 'Number field',
  value: 5,
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 50
}`

For visual help. use this [link](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.1/examples/form/field-types.html)

Comment: a little explanation [or maybe some pseudo-code] will be great.

Comment: Good, but actually it's just a spinner which works with integers, not time values.